# Terraform - How do I map different azure environment variable files?

Tags: azure, terraform, devops, configuration-management

I have below two environments terraform files

1. devenv_variables.tfvars
2. testenv_variables.tfvars

Here is devenv_variables.tfvars

```
 location            = "westeurope"
 resource_group_name = "devenv-cloudresources-rg"
```

Here is testenv_variables.tfvars

```
 location            = "westeurope"
 resource_group_name = "testenv-cloudresources-rg"
```

Here is my `main.tf`

```
  # Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
  provider "azurerm" {
       version = "=2.0.0"

       features {}

       subscription_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

   }

   provider "azurerm" {
       alias  = "testenv"
       subscription_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }


    # Create a resource group
    resource "azurerm_resource_group"  {
        provider = "azurerm.testenv" //How do I pass provider based on variables here?
        name     = "${var.resource_group_name}" 
        location = "${var.location}"
      }
```

My requirement is, based on passed `tfvar` file as parameter, it should choose the subscription.

```
   terraform apply  -var-file="devenv_variables.tfvars"
```

when I type below command resource shall create in test environment

```
   terraform apply  -var-file="testenv_variables.tfvars"
```

I think, I need to define client id, and password to login to respective subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

`tfvars` files should only contain the **values** of variables.
The **declaration** of variables should happen in regular `tf` files.

`variables.tf`

```
    variable "location" { 
      type = "string"
      description = "The azure location where the resources is created"
    }
```

`devenv_variables.tfvars`

```
location     = "West Europe"
```

[This tutorial](https://azurecitadel.com/automation/terraform/lab4/) can also help you with some more information and examples.

Comment: Helped in defining variables, However, could not make it work. I have updated the question.

Comment: This is a completely new question now. You should undo the edit and ask it as a separate question. Ideally, you could also accept this answer since it solved the original problem.

Comment: This tutorial shows you how you can switch between subscriptions easily (altough not with tfvars files): https://azurecitadel.com/automation/terraform/lab5/

Comment: do you have any simple article/sample links? The link you are sharing is for expert DevOps professionals, I am new in to terraform.

Comment: sure, I will undo the question.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do this just make same variable name in both files. when you run the command  `terraform plan–var-file='variable's_file_name'`  &  `terraform apply–var-file='variable's_file_name'`
on that point terraform will get different value from different file.

for demo

variable.tf (contain all variables)

```
variable "resource_group" {
type = string
description = "Resource Group"
default = ""
}
```

dev.tfvars (contain development variable's values)

```
resource_group="name_of_my_resource_group_dev"
```

prod.tfvars (contain production variable's values)

```
resource_group="name_of_my_resource_group_prod"
```

now when you run command `terraform plan–var-file='dev.tfvars'` it take the value from **dev.tfvars** file.